# Upload File to OneDrive using ASP.Net Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have created a simple ASP.Net web forms application and want to upload a file to One Drive. I implemented MS Graph APIs for this purpose. There are three files, Upload.aspx, Upload.aspx.cs, and MsalAuthentication.cs (The code is also given below). When I click on "Upload button" and the control goes to:

`var result = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_scopes, _username, _password).ExecuteAsync();`, it stucks here and doesn't move to the next statement.

In web.Config file, I have also given applicationId and tenantId as:

```
< appSettings >
      < add key="tenantId" value="some id" />
      < add key="applicationId" value="some id" />
   < /appSettings>
```

Can anybody tell me about the issue?
The code is given below

Upload.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Helpers;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace WebFormsOneDrive
{
    public partial class Upload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var config = LoadAppSettings();
            if (config == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid appsettings.json file.");
                return;
            }

            var userName = ReadUsername();
            var userPassword = ReadPassword();

            var client = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(config, userName, userPassword);

            // request 1 - upload small file to user's onedrive
            var fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\webform\upload\", fileName);
            

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            var uploadedFile = client.Me.Drive.Root
                                          .ItemWithPath(fileName)
                                          .Content
                                          .Request()
                                          .PutAsync<DriveItem>(fileStream)
                                          .Result;
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded to: " + uploadedFile.WebUrl);
        }
        private static NameValueCollection LoadAppSettings()
        {
            try
            {
                //var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                //                  .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                //                  .AddXMLFile("Web.config", false, true)
                //                  .Build();
                var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings") as NameValueCollection;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationId"]) ||
                    string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["tenantId"]))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return config;
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private static IAuthenticationProvider CreateAuthorizationProvider(NameValueCollection config, string userName, SecureString userPassword)
        {
            var clientId = config["applicationId"];
            var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{config["tenantId"]}/v2.0";

            List<string> scopes = new List<string>();
            scopes.Add("User.Read");
            scopes.Add("Files.Read");
            scopes.Add("Files.ReadWrite");
            var cca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                                    .WithAuthority(authority)
                                                    .Build();
            return MsalAuthenticationProvider.GetInstance(cca, scopes.ToArray(), userName, userPassword);
        }

        private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(NameValueCollection config, string userName, SecureString userPassword)
        {
            var authenticationProvider = CreateAuthorizationProvider(config, userName, userPassword);
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
            return graphClient;
        }

        private static SecureString ReadPassword()
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter your password");
            //SecureString password = new SecureString();
            //while (true)
            //{
            //    ConsoleKeyInfo c = Console.ReadKey(true);
            //    if (c.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            //    {
            //        break;
            //    }
            //    password.AppendChar(c.KeyChar);
            //    Console.Write("*");
            //}
            //Console.WriteLine();
            var password = new SecureString();
            password.AppendChar('p');
            password.AppendChar('a');
            password.AppendChar('s');
            password.AppendChar('s');
            password.AppendChar('w');
            password.AppendChar('o');
            password.AppendChar('r');
            password.AppendChar('d');
            return password;
        }

        private static string ReadUsername()
        {
            //string username;
            //Console.WriteLine("Enter your username");
            //username = Console.ReadLine();
            //return username;
            string userName = "abcd@domain@onmicrosoft.com";
            return userName;
        }
    }
}
```

MsalAuthentication.cs

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph;

namespace Helpers
{
    public class MsalAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private static MsalAuthenticationProvider _singleton;
        private IPublicClientApplication _clientApplication;
        private string[] _scopes;
        private string _username;
        private SecureString _password;
        private string _userId;

        private MsalAuthenticationProvider(IPublicClientApplication clientApplication, string[] scopes, string username, SecureString password)
        {
            _clientApplication = clientApplication;
            _scopes = scopes;
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
            _userId = null;
        }

        public static MsalAuthenticationProvider GetInstance(IPublicClientApplication clientApplication, string[] scopes, string username, SecureString password)
        {
            if (_singleton == null)
            {
                _singleton = new MsalAuthenticationProvider(clientApplication, scopes, username, password);
            }

            return _singleton;
        }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            var accessToken = await GetTokenAsync();

            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);
        }

        public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userId))
            {
                try
                {
                    var account = await _clientApplication.GetAccountAsync(_userId);

                    if (account != null)
                    {
                        var silentResult = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
                        return silentResult.AccessToken;
                    }
                }
                catch (MsalUiRequiredException) { }
            }

            var result = await _clientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(_scopes, _username, _password).ExecuteAsync();
            _userId = result.Account.HomeAccountId.Identifier;
            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

Comment: You have an empty try/catch in your code. I don't know if that's your problem.....but that could definitely be hiding a bigger problem. Empty catch blocks should never be in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed 2 concepts:

- access on behalf of a user's connection (via AAD for example)
- access via the security of an application (client secret)

In general we cannot pass the password of a user in clear like that to an API, we play with tokens.

The Graph Doc for [all scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS)

Add a client secret to your AAD and give all the roles base you need to your api.

If you use Credential flow, you should not use "Me" in the graph call, but something like : graph.Users["user@email.com"].Drive....

Otherwise if you realy want to use password you can do that :

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
                .GetAsync();
```